# How to convert normal PDF to AcroForm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, pdf.js

I need to create a form filling using exiting PDF fields and need to pre-fill the inputs dynamically.

So is possible to convert a normal PDF to AcroForm in React or directly edit a PDF to add some text in it and replace the text using the position?